# how to Redirect to a html file, if folder exists on Android phone SD card?

Tags: android, cordova, android-sdcard

I want to redirect a user to an html file or website or path, if a folder exists in sd card
 ( example: sdcard/download folder )

I have used response.redirect(); but its not working at all.
I want to use Java by the way.
or if theres another way, like using javascript-and connecting it to java.. is ok also.
any ideas is appreciated. thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a WebView  ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). Load the webview from your layout based on the event, and use it to load the url that you need.

Comment: thanks! studied it and implemented. it worked well :)